# linux with 2 nic for SIP and iptables rules

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, linux-networking, sip

I have a linux machine with 2 NIC, on one where the public ip of my bridged modem is setup

On the other one with local lan
enp7s0: WAN IP
enp6s0: 192.168.0.1

I setup my iptables rules, but it doesn't seem to work out for me.
ip forwarding is activated but it won't make that I want to have done.

Here are my rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Mon Oct  7 00:10:54 2019
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [92:10575]
:INPUT ACCEPT [72:9227]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [20:1348]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [77:8645]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [97:9993]
COMMIT

# Completed on Mon Oct  7 00:10:54 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Mon Oct  7 00:10:54 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [77:8645]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp6s0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i enp7s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5080 -m string --string 
"sipcli" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i enp7s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5080 -m string --string 
"friendly-scanner" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i enp7s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5080 -m string --string 
"VaxSIPUserAgent" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i enp7s0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp6s0 -o enp7s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp7s0 -o enp6s0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct  7 00:10:54 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Mon Oct  7 00:10:54 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [11:741]
:INPUT ACCEPT [11:741]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:120]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:120]
-A PREROUTING -i enp7s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10000:20000 -j DNAT -- 
to-destination 192.168.0.1
-A PREROUTING -i enp7s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j DNAT --to- 
destination 192.168.0.1
-A PREROUTING -i enp7s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5061 -j DNAT --to- 
destination 192.168.0.1
-A POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Oct  7 00:10:54 2019
```

If anybody of you have an idea of what I had done wrong....
Thanks.

best, Tamer

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled IP forwarding?..Always gets me

to check it:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

to set it:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```